# Rotate and reset object rotation with Mouse Input

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I would like to rotate my game object with mouse input but the problem is once I decided to move the mouse in the opposite direction I would like to reset the rotation of GameObject like Quarterion.identity(0,0,0) and then keep the rotation to the other side.

When I release the mouse button, it does what I want it to do, but I'd like to capture this smoothness also in GetMouseButton() , If that doesn't make clear, I explained the idea with picture. All I want to do is make realistic physics.

Picture if it doesn't show up: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXgKt.png

```
if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
{
   swipe= Input.mousePosition.x - mouseStartPos; 
   player.transform.Rotate(0, swipe* 5 * Time.deltaTime, 0f);

}

 if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
{
    swipe= 0;
    player.transform.DORotate(new Vector3(0, 0, 0), 0.1f, RotateMode.Fast); 

//It is returning to the base rotation which I want in GetMouseButton(), if(swipe==0){} strategy was ineffective. It is constantly changing swipe to 0, resulting in no rotation...
```

[image: Demonstration]}

Thank you from now and have a good day, I hope I will get the idea in order to make it.

I tried a lot of different rotation types but couldn't get the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
float? startX;
float? currentX;

void Update() 
{   
    // Set the starting position
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
       startX = Input.mousePosition.x;
    }

    // Ensure no action when startX is not set
    if (startX == null)
        return;
        
    // Rotate while the mouse is moving
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        // Ensure Position Changed
        if (Input.mousePosition.x == currentX)
            return;
            
        
        currentX = Input.mousePosition.x;
        
        // Turn it in the required direction
        // Get a vlue of -1 or 1
        var dir = (currentX.Value  - startX.Value) / Mathf.Abs(currentX.Value - startX.Value);
        
        // Rotate
        player.transform.Rotate(0, dir * 5 * Time.deltaTime, 0f);

    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        startX = null;
        currentX = null;
        player.transform.DORotate(new Vector3(0, 0, 0), 0.1f, RotateMode.Fast); 
    }
}
```

Comment: cannot convert from float? to float and without question marks in console Its giving me red mark called Input rotation is {nan,nan,nan,nan} @MrMoonMan

Comment: Sorry you'll have to use `currentX.Value` or `startX.Value`